# Queries on how to speed up Magento

Tags: optimization

How can I speed up Magento? Looked at lots of tweaks to speed up but still not fast. I have the following queries:

1. Is it better to use `nosql` or is another database recommended?
2. Is `Apache` better than `Ngnix`, or something else recommended?

Are there any other recommendations to speed up Magento?

Comment: _NoSQL or any other database_ not an option unless you can figure out how to rewrite Magento to do that. Many noises have been made about making modules to replace using MySQL, the echos of silence from the development groups announcing this afterwards indicate No. Percona is the only option on this front.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to speed up Magento at the software as well as hardware level.

Firstly, you need to make sure that your server is powerful enough to run Magento. Some users attempt to use a small VM (for example 512MB RAM or less) or cheap shared hosting account and those will not cut it.

For your two queries:-

1. Magento uses InnoDB as it's storage engine. Percona Server with XtraDB will be a good drop-in replacement to Oracle's MySQL.
2. Nginx is pretty good but not a proper drop-in replacement for Apache so you will need to change some of the ways you do things. For a drop-in replacement web server to Apache, LiteSpeed Web Server (Enterprise version) is the best so far but it is a commercial web server with licensing fee.

You may also want to implement multiple caching system, including OPCache like APC / XCache / eAccelerator / ZendCache, Memory based cache like Memcached / Redis and also Page cache like Varnish / LiteSpeed Dynamic Content Cache (aka LiteSpeed Cache).

Comment: i think both are paid , i will prefer using shared hosting still i do not get that much speed

Comment: To confirm, what hosting platform are you using now? Shared hosting doesn't allow you to modify any of the software softeare in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to provide some details of what you are trying to achieve, such as number of stores, categories, products, budget for capital investment and ongoing per month , performance goals. Technically you can add many different solutions such as APC, Redis, Percona, but you will spend all your time trying to make it faster and forget that you need to actually run a business.

Answer (score 1):

Magento wrote a about it, they have documents on their site about performance and scalability.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/performance-scalability/

They compare Apache vs Nginx. Where Nginx is the clear winner.
You can look at some FullPageCache modules out there which can make your site even faster.

There are some best practices which settings to choose for MySQL, using Redis caching, etcetera.

I would recommend to take a close look at what is already out there.
And choose your hosting company wisely.

Comment: Nginx isn't really the clear winner, I see no real comparisson because the circumstances aren't the same. For one, Apache tests used mod-php and not PHP-FPM so the php speed difference is caused by the PHP processor there. Second, apache does not cache any static files, that's where nginx gains the advantage, this is easily counterable by using a CDN or varnish for static file caching tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried Redis?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee

This made a huge difference for me.